# How to remove white space above and below leaflet map on Quarto website

Tags: r, quarto, r-leaflet

I am using Quarto to develop a website featuring a leaflet map. I'm not sure how to remove the white spaces above and below the map on the webpage:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4ge1.png)

This should ideally take up the entire space between the header and the footer.

Details of the _quarto.yaml are here:

```
project:
  type: website

website:
  title: "Quarto website"
  navbar:
    left:
      - href: index.qmd
        text: Home
      - about.qmd
  page-footer: 
   border: false
   background: primary
   left: "Published with [Quarto](https://quarto.org/)"

format:
  html:
    theme: cosmo
    css: styles.css
    toc: true

editor: visual
```

And details of the index.qmd are here:

````
```{r}
#| label: setup
#| include: false

library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)
```

```{r}
#| label: map
#| echo: false
#| warning: false
#| column: screen

leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB", group = "CartoDB")
```
````

Any help would be much appreciated!